# Is there a way to group a series of events by date on SQL. ie Get the minimum and max event times that happen for every empid(employee) and day

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This code would group all the events between the selected times. Is there a way that the max and min events could be grouped by date automatically without having to specify the dates like I have. ie Get the max and min events for each day grouped by ID.

```
SELECT MIN(ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC) AS Time_In, MAX(ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC) AS Time_Out, EMPID
    FROM dbo.EVENTS ev 
    WHERE (ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC  
    BETWEEN '2019-04-09'
    AND '2019-04-09 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY EMPID
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Just DON'T use an inclusive upper bound. Why? Because you have probably made a common mistake in assuming that the maximum time portion of a datetime value. That is not accurate for datetime nor datetime2 and it is FAR safer to use the exclusive upper boundary of the next date at 00:00:00.

Comment: The short answer is to use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) where you simply join the calendar table to your source table on date to get the range of dates you desire. A calendar table can be dynamically generated using a CTE if you do not have an actual one (but you should - it has so many uses).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  empid
, CAST(event_time_utc AS DATE) AS event_dt
, MIN(event_time_utc)          AS time_in
, MAX(event_time_utc)          AS time_out
FROM events
GROUP BY 
  empid
, CAST(event_time_utc AS DATE)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
SELECT EMPID, MIN(ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC) AS Time_In,
       MAX(ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC) AS Time_Out, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN EVENT END) as first_event,
       MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum_desc = 1 THEN EVENT END) as last_event
FROM (SELECT ev.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM FROM dbo.EVENTS ev 
      WHERE ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC >- '2019-04-09' AND ev.EVENT_TIME_UTC < '2019-04-10'
     ) e
GROUP BY EMPID;
```